# Excel Pivot Table select rows based on column, with all columns displayed

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I am using Excel 2010.
Below is an anonymized sample of my data.

```
Name    Factor  Nick Town
Anton   0   Anton   Denver
Anton   1   Anton1  Boston
Anton   2   AntonB  Miami
Anton   1   Anton1  Seattle
Bernard 0   Bernard Denver
Bernard 1   Bernie  Miami
Bernard 1   Bernardo    Seattle
Chuck   0   Chuck   Denver
Chuck   1   Chuckee Chicago
Chuck   2   Chuckee Seattle
Chuck   2   Chucky  Miami
Chuck   1   Tchuk   Chicago
Chuck   2   Chuck   Houston
Deborah 0   Deborah Denver
Deborah 1   Deb Miami
Deborah 2   Debbie  Chicago
Deborah 3   Debbee  Boston
Deborah 1   Debbie  Boston
```

**What I want:**
For each Name which is referred in a specific town (say Chicago), I want all the towns where they are referred.

Something like:

[image]

In SQL, I would have expressed that as:

```
select distinct Name , town from Dist 
  where Name in (select Name from Dist where town='Chicago');
```

**My process:**
I need the list of towns for each Name. It is quite simple. 
[image: Names and Towns]

My issue comes in when I want this list filtered to only the Names having Chicago in their list. If I filter on Chicago, I get the following:

[image: Names filtered on a town]

- I tried to duplicate the town field to be able to filter on the first and display the second. This did not work.
- I tried various moves between columns and rows, with no success.
- I don't even see how to compute a column to reach my goal.

If this could be achieved without Pivot Tables, I am ok with this. I just thought it would be easier.

Comment: What's wrong with the result you achieved? Can you mock up what you want the result to look like?

Comment: @OldUgly The result I want is the picture in "What I want". It is a mockup. The two last pictures are the one I can get; they are real screenshots.

Comment: Well, actually, in the mockup, the Boston column should not be there. It is a leftover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a helper column to your source data. Supposing that name is in column A and Town is in column D, your formula will be (in E2):

`=COUNTIF(A:A,A2,D:D,"Chicago")`

This will return `1` for names having Chicago, and `0` for names without Chicago. (*same logic as your subquery would do in SQL*)

Just add this new column for your pivot table filter and filter for `1`.

Comment: It validates my second thought that I need one column for each town. Or, at least an external cell with the town I want to use as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Select the column headers and right click. Select field settings > layout and print. And toggle show items with no data.

[image]

Comment: This will display all cities, but won't display counts in them:(

Comment: Well, that's simply. If you want it to give the counts, then you should change the pivot table options so that, value field displays "count"?

Comment: This does not work. Try with the provided data sample.